# binding couldbees-hosted database to Play app

Tags: cloudbees

Does it work for anyone? I used 
    bees app:bind 
command and although it bound the app and db, (as shown by bees app:bindings) it did not show any db credential variables it created (neither I could just use them in application.config).

I tried setting those credential variables via 
    bees config:set
but running the app via 
    play run
still threw a dereferencing error.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sure it work, we use it on [this app](https://github.com/breizhjug/breizhcamp-cfp)
see the db.* properties on [conf file](https://github.com/BreizhJUG/Breizhcamp-cfp/blob/master/conf/cloudbees.conf)